# UITableViewCell getting highlighted during scrolling, then selected later

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.iOS app with a UITableView. There is only one section in the view. If I put my finger on one row of the table (say, row number 5), hold it for a moment, then scroll the table view, the row becomes highlighted. That's mildly undesirable, but no big deal. BUT if I then tap another row (say row number 10) to select it, my UITableViewSource object gets a RowSelected callback with the originally touched row. That is a big problem, because the app now thinks the user has selected the wrong row. Furthermore, I can't see any callback that arrives with the correct tapped row.

I've tried to hack fix this by deselecting the row when scrolling ends. It doesn't help.

I have a non-Xamarin version of the app that does not exhibit this behavior.

Here is some of my code (from a custom UITableViewSource subclass), and the output:

```
public int HighlightedRowIndex {get;set;} = -1;

public override void RowHighlighted(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath rowIndexPath) {
  // I actually don't want to be looking at highlighted at all; I'm just going here to try to understand/fix the problem.
  CommonDebug.LogLine("row highlighted", (int)rowIndexPath.Row);
  this.HighlightedRowIndex = rowIndexPath.Row;
}

public override void DraggingEnded(UIScrollView scrollView, bool willDecelerate) {
  int highlighted = this.HighlightedRowIndex;
  if (highlighted >= 0) {
    NSIndexPath indexPath = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0, (nint)highlighted);
    UITableView tableView = scrollView as UITableView;
    if (tableView!=null) {
      CommonDebug.LogLine("ATTEMPTING HACK FIX, BUT IT DOES NOT HELP");
      //  tableView.SelectRow(indexPath, false, UITableViewScrollPosition.None); // This can be commented out, or not; it doesn't help either way.
      tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, false);
    }
  }
  this.HighlightedRowIndex = -1;
}

public override bool ShouldHighlightRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath rowIndexPath) {
  CommonDebug.LogLine("should highlight", (int)rowIndexPath.Row);
  // Returning false from here would prevent the problem, but would also prevent any selection . . .
  return true;
}

public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath) {
  CommonDebug.LogLine("IOSListViewSource selected", indexPath.Row);
  if (this.SelectIgnoreCount == 0) {
    ListViewSectionModel model = this.GetModel();
    int row = (int)indexPath.Row;
    model.SelectItem(row);
  } else {
    CommonDebug.LogLine("ignoring");
  }
}
```

output:

I put my finger on row 5, let it linger there a moment, then scroll the table view:

```
should highlight 5
row highlighted 5
ATTEMPTING HACK FIX, BUT IT DOES NOT HELP
```

then I tap row 10:

```
WillSelectRow 5
IOSListViewSource selected 5
```

No indication I can find that row 10 was tapped.

Has anyone had the same problem / found a work-around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it:

```
public int HighlightedRowIndex {get;set;} = -1;

public override void DraggingEnded(UIScrollView scrollView, bool willDecelerate) {
  int highlighted = this.HighlightedRowIndex;
  if (highlighted >= 0) {
    UITableView tableView = scrollView as UITableView;
    if (tableView!=null) {
      tableView.ReloadData();
    }
  }
  this.HighlightedRowIndex = -1;
}

public override void RowHighlighted(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath rowIndexPath) {
  this.HighlightedRowIndex = rowIndexPath.Row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar way to do so is to add custom Delegate to UITableView(List). I did this way because subclassing UITableViewSource was bad idea in my case.

Define custom delegate and override Scrolled function:

```
public class CustDelegate : UITableViewDelegate
 {
    private CustomListViewRenderer list { get; set; }
    public CustDelegate(CustomListViewRenderer listRenderer)
        : base()
    {
        list = listRenderer;
    }
    public override void Scrolled(UIScrollView scrollView)
    {
        if(list != null)
            list.Scrolled();
    }
}
```

Add delegate to UITableView in ListRenderer

```
(UITableView)Control.Delegate = new CustDelegate(this);
```

And define Scrolled function that will prevent highlighting.

Hope this will be useful for someone.